# How to export a DataFrame to Cloud Storage?

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a DataFrame that's made from a BigQuery table. I've done some transformation on this table and now I need to export it to Cloud Storage as a .txt file with (; delimiter).

I'm using a Datalab Notebook.

How to load this transformed table as a file to a specific bucket ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [gcsfs](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) installed, you can simply use a google cloud storage url:

```py
df.to_csv('gs://bucket/path/to/file.txt')
```

Comment: How to define the delimiter ?

Comment: You can use all the normal [`pd.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) arguments, in this case, `sep=';'`